# problem in reading a dataframe from a csv file: Delimiter is used in one of the designed variables

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to use the pandas function: read_csv to obtain a dataframe containing 3 columns (the first is a string , the 2nd is a datetime64 and the third is a list of lists ). The CSV is written as shown below :

```
**Jack**   ,   1590491881000 , [[1,0.61],[2,0.23],[3,0.89]]
**Mark**   ,   1590407272000 , [[1,0.24],[2,0.36],[3,0.93]]
```

I simplified the list because in reality there are over 1000 lists in the list of lists.

Also, the format of the timestamp is converted somehow, so I figured I could obtain the exact date using:

```
np.datetime64(1590491881000, 'ms')
```

The problem is when I use read_csv, I get several columns depending on the delimiter: ",", the rows also get mixed up, but what I need is to only have 3 columns. Also, the names of the columns are given to the last "detected" columns.

I tried this, but it did not work :

```
fields = ['Client','Timestamp','Measurements']
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", names = fields, dtype={"Client": str , "Timestamp": str , "Measurements" : str })
```

Are there some adjustments that I can make to the read_csv function to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the delimiter in your csv file via find and replace?

Comment: I would to need to change only the first two  "," in each row (and there are over 6000 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the csv-file is broken.  The separator used for field separation is also found in the last field's data, and there is no way to tell them apart without prior knowledge.

In this particular example, extending the separator to a string like ' , ' will do what you want, i.e.

```
df = pandas.read_csv("file", names = fields, dtype={"Client": str , "Timestamp": str , "Measurements" : str }, sep=' , ', engine='python')
```

Ideally, the csv-file should be fixed.  Write a filter in python or awk or something and replace the actual field separators by some unique character not found elsewhere in the file.

Answer (score 0):

CSV has just 4 rules:

1. Values are separated by commas
2. rows are separated by cr-lf, but many apps support either alone
3. If a value contains a cr, lf, comma, put it in "
4. If a value has a literal ", double it.

Revise your csv file for proper double quoting.  What produced it?